# Comparing absolute values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality, contest-math

> If $|i - (a + bi)| < 1$ does $|i - (a - bi)| < 1$ also?

I would say yes, because the absolute value shouldn't differ by more than $1$?

Where $i = \sqrt{-1}$

Comment: Can you try constructing counterexamples? What should the value of $b$ be for the first condition to hold?

Comment: @Element118, I cannot, which is why I am asking if the claim is true?

Comment: Check out $a=0$ and $b=1.9$

Comment: Intuitively speaking, if $a+bi$ is close to $i$, must $a-bi$ also be close to $i$?

Answer (score 1):

$$|i-(0.9+i)|=0.9$$, 
$$|i-(0.9-i)|= 2.193...$$
as you can see in the latter case multiplying through the negative gives you $2i$, and so ultimately you result in:

$$  \sqrt{( 0.9^2+2^2)}>1 $$

Comment: Steps omitted because of the tag contest math, if it is a content it is important to prove these things to yourself.